# I want to develop a theme using WordPress. Which theme should I start from or develop from scratch?

Tags: themes

I want to develop a WordPress theme similar to another theme present on the internet. Shall I use the default WordPress theme to start from or start from scratch?

Please guide me.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot help you with this as it is entirely up to you and your specific needs and what you need to achieve. There are many skeleton themes available out there to use as a base. I have also in the past successfully used twentytwelve and twentyfourteen as base themes and have even merged the two themes into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with WordPress TwentyFifteen or any other default theme.

You don't have re-invent the wheel, you will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://underscores.me/) basic theme with default features that should begginer person to know.

- A just right amount of lean, well-commented, modern, HTML5 templates.
- A helpful 404 template.
- An optional sample custom header implementation in inc/custom-header.php
- Custom template tags in inc/template-tags.php that keep your templates clean and neat and prevent code duplication.
- Some small tweaks in inc/extras.php that can improve your theming experience.
- A script at js/navigation.js that makes your menu a toggled dropdown on small screens (like your phone), ready for CSS artistry.
- 2 sample CSS layouts in layouts/: A sidebar on the right side of your content and a sidebar on the left side of your content.
  Smartly organized starter CSS in style.css that will help you to quickly get your design off the ground.
- The GPL license in license.txt.

Use it to make something cool.

Answer (score 0):

For learning & understanding I think you should start from [wordpress blank theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/blankslate/)